# Qt: Have parent Widget class draw something in addition to the child class widget

Tags: qt

More and more this seems like a philosophical `Qt` question:

I have a widget representing a window `A`.
I have a widget representing a window, deriving from `A`, called `B`.

B draws its stuff, but I want `A` to contribute some drawing, *e.g.* draw an image OVER what `B` draws. I want `B` to be completely unaware of this, not having to cooperate with `A` other than deriving from it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override [`event()`](http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qwidget.html#event) in A:

```
bool A::event ( QEvent * e)
{
  bool handled = QWidget::event(e);
  if(e->type() == QEvent::Paint) {
    // cast e to QPaintEvent and do the overlay painting
  }
  return handled;
}
```

Comment: I am doing just that, but no drawing occurs. the code gets executed, but no effect on what's shown. The scary thing is, even if I comment out the "QWidget:event(e)" line, and return TRUE or FALSE, the drawing of B still occurs normally - i can't understand this, it's like "A" is being completely bypassed. how can it draw if I remove the calls?

Comment: If you've overridden event() in B, you need to call A::event() in it. If you only override only paintEvent in B, then set a breakpoint there to see where it's called from.

Comment: I just overrode A::event - it gets called. The breakpoint is reached, but nothing I do there changes ANYTHING as far as what gets drawn. I just don't understand why.

Comment: when putting a breakpoint in A::event, the call stack is:0 a::event a.cpp 173 0x0000000100007830 
1 QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper  0 0x000000010011fddd 
2 QApplication::notify  0 0x000000010012672d 
3 QCoreApplication::notifyInternal  0 0x0000000100d6adec 
4 qt_sendSpontaneousEvent  0 0x000000010011fe7c 
5

Comment: If A::event is the only thing you override in both A and B then there's something wrong with your painting in A. Post some code that demonstrator the problem. Both .h and .cpp for A and B will help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no QT expert, but you could do this in a hacky way by having A delegate its drawing to a child component of identical size located at (0,0). Naturally, the child component would be drawn after your window widget in the hierarchy, and so this would achieve what you're after.